# Remainder of $\sum_{x=1}^{312} x \times x!$ divided by 2016

Tags: summation, contest-math, factorial, sums-of-squares

I have this question:

> > What is the remainder of $$\sum_{x=1}^{312} x \times x!$$ (or just simply)
> >     $$(1! \times 1) + (2! \times 2) + (3! \times 3) + \dots + (312! \times312)$$
> >     Divided by $2016$?

Comment: What contest is this from?  Is it still on-going?

Comment: What contest is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$n\cdot n!=(n+1-1)\cdot n!=(n+1)!-(n)!$$

Do you know Telescoping Series?

$$\sum_{r=n}^m r\cdot r!= (m+1)!-n!$$

Here $n=1, m=312$

Now $2016=7\cdot3^2\cdot2^5$